# My background image is not completely covering the whole page

Tags: html, css, image, background, format

I have a simple page. And I have an image that I want to place on that page. I would like said image to cover entire page not just 65% of page.

```
<style>
body  {

  background-image: url(images/new5.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;


}
</style>
```

Comment: Try to add `background-size: cover;` or `background-size: contain;`, it will stretch the image to cover the whole page but it will affect the image quality. To avoid that, try to use a larger size image.

Comment: Thanks Kim! That worked, however,  it's just a bit out of focus now. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: Try to add an `image-rendering`. You can read more [here](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-css/image-rendering.html) or [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref//css3_pr_image-rendering.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body { 
background-image: url(images/new5.jpg); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;}
```

The background image will take the full length and width.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

html {
    height:100%;
}

body { 
     background-image: url(images/new5.jpg); 
     background-position:center;
     background-size:cover;
}
```